# Security of this parallelizable two-pass authentication scheme

Tags: block-cipher, mac, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation

This is only the authentication half of a block cipher mode of operation that provides authenticated encryption. The part that provides encryption is left out (it can be CBC, PCBC, ECB, or whatever).

Suppose that:

- $E(k,x)$ is the encryption of data block $x$ using key $k$.
- $D(k,x)$ is the decryption of data block $x$ using key $k$.
- $K$ is the key used for authentication.
- $N$ is the nonce used for authentication.
- $x_i$ is the $i$<sup>th</sup> zero-based data block.
- $a_i$ is an authentication tag for the $i$<sup>th</sup> zero-based data block.
- $A$ is the authentication tag for the entire data stream.
- $n$ is the number of data blocks.
- $F(x)=E(K, N) \boxplus (x \oplus (x \ggg 1))$.
- $a_i=E(K, x_i \oplus F(i))$.
- $A=E(K, a_0 \oplus a_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus a_{n-2} \oplus a_{n-1})$.

It is my hope that the XORing each data block's authentication tag is similar to the repeated multiplication in a Galois field as found in Galois/counter mode.

Comment: This is not the forum for asking for assessment of crypto designs.  It's your responsibility to prove that the IND-CCA3/AE security of this system is not much worse than the IND-CPA security of $E$ as a function of the computational cost, the number of queries to oracles, the lengths of the messages involved, _etc._  See, _e.g._, the [SIV paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/siv/keywrap.pdf), or many of the [CAESAR submissions](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar-submissions.html), for examples.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I'm not looking for an assessment of designs. I made this so any responses I can get help me understand authenticated encryption.

Comment: Can you phrase that as a more specific question, then?